# difference of upgradeable read lock vs a write lock in C# ReaderWriteLock

Tags: c#, multithreading

Whats the difference between an upgradeable read lock and a write lock in the ReaderWriterLock class?

Based on the MSDN description, only one thread can enter an upgradeable read lock. If I follow correctly, I could just forget about upgrading it since its the same as a write lock.
Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Do you mean ReaderWriterLockSlim?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(I'm assuming you mean `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, as I don't think `ReaderWriterLock` has an upgradeable read mode.)

Although only one thread can enter an upgradeable read lock, one thread can have an upgradeable read lock *and other threads can still enter a read lock*:

> Only one thread can enter upgradeable mode at any given time. If a thread is in upgradeable mode, and there are no threads waiting to enter write mode, any number of other threads can enter read mode, even if there are threads waiting to enter upgradeable mode.

Compare that with a write lock:

> When there are threads waiting to enter write mode, additional threads that try to enter read mode or upgradeable mode block until all the threads waiting to enter write mode have either timed out or entered write mode and then exited from it.

In other words, a write lock is entirely exclusive, whereas an upgradeable read lock will allow other threads to keep entering/exiting for read mode *until the upgrade is needed*.

Comment: I think the MSDN example (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.enterupgradeablereadlock.aspx) would be more succinct if it had only used one write lock. Upgradeable read locks make sense only if there is a read lock on same `ReaderWriterLockSlim` instance somewhere else in the code. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: Followed the example in the above comment link
Exception: The write lock is being released without being held
on this line:  cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
Note: I did call a external service within the writeLock, then the locks were released

Answer (score 3):

I think that UpgradableReadLock is a special ReadLock that can be turned into a WriteLock. What MSDN states is that only one thread can turn into WriteLock at the time. This is logical as there can be only one writer.

Comment: But not only the upgradeable lock can be turned into a write lock. The point is that as opposed to a write lock, an upgradeable lock does not allow writing and does **not block other readers**, and also that **there could only be a single upgradeable lock at a time**.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to keep in mind is that **if there is a thread currently holding the upgradable read lock** (by previously calling `EnterUpgradeableReadLock()`)**, then only that thread is able to acquire the write lock** (hence *upgrading*).

Consider the following scenario, where you want to add an `int n` to a list only if `n` is unique (i.e. not already present in the list):

1. `EnterUpgradeableReadLock()`;
2. Check whether the list already contains `n`;
3. If `n` is present in the list, then `ExitUpgradeableReadLock()` and `return`;
4. If `n` is not present in the list, then `EnterWriteLock()` and update the list, followed by `ExitWriteLock()` and `ExitUpgradeableReadLock()`.

The abovementioned restriction prevents other threads running a different logic from grabbing the write lock and making unwanted updates to the list between steps 2 and 4, which could cause our thread to insert a duplicate value.