# C# locking on only distinct objects (not by threads)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, locking

I have a WS that returns information about a trading symbol. I want to cache the results of the WS locally. WS lookups should be performed concurrently for different symbols, but only 1 lookup at a time for each distinct symbol. I can't seem to do both of these things.

Here is a simple version of the locking I am trying:

```
private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _cacheLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _symbolLock = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
private readonly MemoryCache _cache = MemoryCache.Default;

public TradingItem GetLinking(string symbol)
{
    lock (_symbolLock.GetOrAdd(symbol, new object()))
    {
        _cacheLock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
        try
        {
            if (_cache.Contains(symbol))
            {
                return _cache.GetCacheItem(symbol);
            }

            TradingItem item = _resolverService.getLinking(symbol);                   
            _cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                _cache.Set(symbol, item, new CacheItemPolicy());
                return item;
            }
            finally
            {
                _cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _cacheLock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
        }
    }
}
```

As a side, this looks very strange but seems to do what I want in unit testing:

```
lock (_symbolLock.GetOrAdd(symbol, new object()))
```

**My question is**, 
How can I make the WS call `_resolverService.getLinking(symbol)` concurrent? Distinct symbols are currently getting throttled.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just perform the call before you enter the write lock.  That code isn't using the cache, so it doesn't need to synchronize with other cache access for that method call, and you're *already* synchronizing with any other calls to the same symbol, so as long as you only need to prevent concurrent calls for the same symbol, you're already set to just move that one line of code to before you grab the write lock.

This of course assumes that `_resolverService` is able to concurrently get the linking for different symbols.  If it isn't, then you can't perform them concurrently.

Your code also prohibits any concurrency as you're using only ever taking out upgradable read locks, not read locks, of which there can only be one concurrent upgradable reader.  You need to have regular read locks in order to have concurrency, and in order to ensure that your code doesn't deadlock you'll need to ensure that the write is outside of the read lock.

Comment: You are right - but I'm sorry, I posted a bug IRL my call was outside the write lock. I've corrected the code.

Comment: ah so there is a difference between an upgradable read and a normal read? What is the use of the upgradable read then, I wonder.

Comment: @Noah Read the documentation for the type; it covers the various lock types and their behavior.

Comment: Similar discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696238/difference-of-upgradeable-read-lock-vs-a-write-lock-in-c-sharp-readerwritelock